# List aggregated result over group by column in aws athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, group-by, amazon-athena, presto

I have a table with the below schema

```
Test Name, Marks
```

A few entries are : (maths,78),(maths,90),(English,20),(English,40)

Now I wish to group this table on 'Test Name' such that the output=

```
maths [78,90], English [20,40]
```

In AWS Athena. I really can't see any aggregation function doing this on the 'group by' clause on internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *array_agg* function:

```
WITH example_table AS
 (SELECT 'Maths' as test_name, 78 as marks UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Maths', 90 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'English', 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'English', 40)
SELECT test_name, array_agg(marks) as marks
FROM example_table
GROUP BY test_name
```

and if you need something more fancy on the values you can add the *reduce* function:

```
WITH example_table AS
 (SELECT 'maths' as test_name, 78 as marks UNION ALL
  SELECT 'maths', 90 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'English', 20 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'English', 40)
SELECT test_name, reduce(array_agg(marks), ARRAY[], (s, x) -> s || x, s -> s) as marks
FROM example_table
GROUP BY test_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `array_agg()`?

```
select test_name, array_agg(marks)
from t
group by test_name;
```